# complex scalar field as a sum of scalar and pseudoscalar fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cpt-symmetry

Let's consider theory of a complex scalar field
$$\phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(s+\imath p)$$
Is it true that under CPT transformations $s$ is a scalar field and $p$ is a pseudoscalar field?

Comment: Yes. CPT is an anti-linear anti-unitary operator.